# google chrome console "Failed to load resource" problems

Tags: google-chrome, console

I have a page and when I open it in google chrome and see in the console of the debugging tool, I get the following message as shown in the picture.[image: error display]

I do not have those four .gif images and I do not need them too but from where and how am I getting this error message? I have NOT used those four images in any of my code but still getting those message, I could not understand.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CSS. They are likely getting loaded there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check browser add-ons and plugins. Some of them works in background and produce some errors the browser shows you in the console.